# insert programmatically a panel inside an easyui accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

I'm using an accordion with [jeasyui](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php) (version 1.4.1, with jquery version 2.1.3, on a recent firefox 31.3, Linux/Debian/Sid x86-64)

The accordion has a somehow sorted (by the AJAX application, to be released under GPLv3) sequence of panels.

I would like to insert a new accordion panel in the "middle" (i.e. inside) of the accordion.

Apparently, the `$('#accordionid').accordion('add')` function is only appending a panel at the end.

Or should I create a `<div>` and add it to the accordion `div` with DOM manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [EasyUI - How to add a new Item of Accordion on the top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864178/easyui-how-to-add-a-new-item-of-accordion-on-the-top/31067537#31067537) for a similar problem. The idea is to manipulate the div after it is added, but in order to do this you need to be able to identify the elements of the accordion, so you will need to use a unique id to them.